# Como salvar uma imagem gerada pelo php gd?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jcrop

Estou tentando utilizar o jcrop + php gd para fazer cortes em imagem e salvar em outro diretorio porem não sei qual o problema do meu codigo:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src = 'teste/imagem.jpg';
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);

    exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="http://deepliquid.com/Jcrop/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_files/demos.css" type="text/css" />

        <script language="Javascript">

            $(function(){

                $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    onSelect: updateCoords
                });

            });

            function updateCoords(c)
            {
                $('#x').val(c.x);
                $('#y').val(c.y);
                $('#w').val(c.w);
                $('#h').val(c.h);
            };

            function checkCoords()
            {
                if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
                alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
                return false;
            };

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="outer">
    <div class="jcExample">
    <div class="article">

        <h1>Crop jQuery</h1>

        <img src="teste/imagem.jpg" id="cropbox" />
        <form action="crop.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
            <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
            <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
            <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
            <input type="submit" value="Crop Image" />
        </form>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `imagepng($imagem, $NomeDeSaida);` para png ou `imagejpeg($imagem, $NomeDeSaida);` para jpg

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src = 'teste/imagem.jpg';
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
    imagejpeg($dst_r, $NomeDeSaida);

//header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
//imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);

    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para redimensionar e salvar uma imagem no PHP, você pode usar a biblioteca GD do PHP, que fornece funções para manipulação de imagens. Abaixo está um exemplo básico que redimensiona uma imagem para um tamanho específico e salva a imagem redimensionada em um arquivo.

```
    <?php
if (isset($_FILES['nomearquivo'])) {
//pegando a extensao do arquivo
    $new_name = strtolower($_FILES['nomearquivo']['name']); //definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
    $dir = './img/'; //diretorio de uploads

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['nomearquivo']['tmp_name'], $dir . $new_name); //fazer upload do arquivo
}

// Caminho da imagem original
$imagem_original = './img/'.$new_name;

// Abre a imagem original
$imagem = imagecreatefrompng($imagem_original);

// Largura e altura desejadas para a imagem redimensionada
$nova_largura = 300;
$nova_altura = 300;

// Cria uma nova imagem com o tamanho desejado
$nova_imagem = imagecreatetruecolor($nova_largura, $nova_altura);

// Redimensiona a imagem original para a nova imagem
imagecopyresampled($nova_imagem, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nova_largura, $nova_altura, imagesx($imagem), imagesy($imagem));

// Salva a nova imagem em um arquivo
imagepng($nova_imagem, './img/'.$new_name);

// Libera a memória usada pelas imagens
imagedestroy($imagem);
imagedestroy($nova_imagem);
?>
```

Neste exemplo, a função imagecreatefrompng é usada para abrir a imagem original, imagecreatetruecolor é usada para criar uma nova imagem com a largura e altura desejadas, imagecopyresampled é usada para redimensionar a imagem original para a nova imagem e imagepng é usada para salvar a nova imagem em um arquivo.

Certifique-se de ter a extensão GD habilitada no seu servidor PHP para usar essas funções.